# MongDB query sort over memory limit while using index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

I have a SensorData collection which always contains the following fields: *_id*, *datetimeMeasure*, *sensorId*, *originalDataId* and *value* and has the following index, next to the default id index: *{ "sensorId" : 1, "datetimeMeasure" : -1 }*

When executing the query below through Loopback (NodeJS) I get the following error: *Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.*

```
// Loopback query
SensorData.find({
    where: {
        sensorId: { inq: [] /* array with sensor ids */ },
        datetimeMeasure: { between: ["2018-12-24T23:00:00.000Z", "2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"] }
    }
});

// Mongo query (Loopback seems to automatically add the sort)
find({
  sensorId: { $in: [] /* array with sensor ids */ },
  datetimeMeasure: {  
    $gte: "2018-12-24T23:00:00.000Z",
    $lte: "2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
}).sort({ datetimeMeasure: -1 })
```

When I check the query logs I can see that the index is used (IXSCAN). What could be the issue?

I'm using mongo 4.0.6 with Loopback 3.25.0 on NodeJS 10.15.0

Comment: That sort is likely the problem. See if you can convince Loopback to not do that.

Comment: When I add the index { datetimeMeasure: -1 }, that will be used for sorting so the error disappears. How can I validate that the existing compound index will still be used for fetching the data and that it's not doing a COLLSCAN?

Comment: You use [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) to check the query plan.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try out using an aggregation pipeline as it can spool to disk during large queries.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/

So you command would be something like

```
aggregate([{
  $match: {
    sensorId: { $in: [] /* array with sensor ids */ },
    datetimeMeasure: {  
      $gte: "2018-12-24T23:00:00.000Z",
      $lte: "2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"
    }   
  }
}, { $sort: { datetimeMeasure: -1 } } ], { allowDiskUse: true })
```